# Does an API exist to grab cricket match statistics

Tags: web-services, api, web-applications, statistics

As espn cricinfo is built with tons of statistics around the world it is the best source as per my knowledge to get statistics to query and come up with solutions based on the stats. But espn doesn't not offer an API to get the data set. Is there any other way to get the needed set of data of matches played by a country etc. http://developer.espn.com/ does not have a API call for cricket sadly :( Please help me out 
thanks

Comment: http://www.apihub.com/apis/entertainment/sports/cricket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ESPN still does not provide api for cricket. The Athlete API does not contain cricket yet. Anyway it is displayed as coming soon.

[Athletes API Support page](http://espn.huntandgather.com/devcenter/detail-athletes.html#using-the-api)

Comment: link is not working now :(

Comment: Seems they have completely revamped the structure of their APIs - Seems Now they don't offer it categorized by the sport. http://espn.go.com/apis/devcenter/docs/